# call win32 API in flex to access files on network

Tags: apache-flex, winapi, air, flash-builder

I'm working with Adobe Air3.5 .Creating my desktop application on Flex. 
 My purpose is to access my folders which are on network and required authentication to access. But couldn't find any solution to this issue. 
 Any opinion about this? As a solution, how to use win API in flex ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: If you want execute/access native application. you can use NativeProcess(only for localmachine) in Adobe AIR so that you can access native process(like execute some command through command prompt).                                                            you can try to use .Net Webservice to access your Win API and network folder through Flex RPC(Remote Object, HttpService, Webservice) calls (Use some other Server Script (PHP,JSP) to access your folder and your Win API)

Comment: @RajaJaganathan I need to call win32 api in the same process directly.

Comment: @www.Flextras.com "couldn't find any solution to this issue" so tried nothing yet. Waiting for clues

Comment: In AIR use the File class http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html to access directories that the machine has access to.  I would expect the OS to handle authentication "magically".  Native Process or Native Extensions can be used for calling Windows APIs [on Windows] but you shouldn't need that just to access a file.

Comment: @www.Flextras.com "magically" you are right, but in process not:( As you told, I used File class,OS does not handle authentication, _file.exists method returns false, so I couldn't access my files on network.Yes, I shouldn't nedd that just to access a file,thanks

Comment: @nthere9 You didn't tell us that you used the File class.  It would be great information to add to your original question so we don't go about suggesting things that you already tried.

Comment: @www.Flextras.com I applied your suggestion 'File' class. Not before your suggest.It took few minutes to check it and methods of File Class,Thanks